# What is the proper way to do conditional react state updates in non-hook react with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate, react-typescript

I'm trying to do a conditional state update in react where some keys are only updated if another value changes (used to reset some values for settings to null if certain modes are selected).  This pattern used to work fine (like years ago), but now it seems like React's setState expects a Pick object instead of Partial, which works great if inlining your state object into the setState call, but prevents conditional construction of the state object to update.

Attempted code below, fails due to setState not taking a partial. newValue is a numeric parameter to the change handler function that this code excerpt is from.

```
const newState: Partial<localState> = {};
if (newValue !== 2) {
    newState.settingA = null;
    newState.settingTwo = null;
}
newState.multiCurrencyDynamicMode = newValue;
this.setState(newState);
```

I tried switching newState to `const newState: Pick<localState, keyof localState>` but this fails due to this definition of pick expecting every key of localState to be present.

Comment: Typescript 4.8.4, React 18.2.0, @types/react 18.0.26.  Exact error message: `TS2345: Argument of type  Partial<localState>  is not assignable to parameter of type localState | Pick<localState, keyof localState> | ((prevState: Readonly<localState>, props: Readonly<params>) => localState | ... 1 more ... | null) | null`

Answer (score 1):

The definition for `Partial` is:

```
/**
 * Make all properties in T optional
 */
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
```

So, without seeing how `localstate` is defined in your code, I'm guessing that it doesn't allow undefined properties; but by using `Partial`, it's effectively creating this as the type:

```
// Partial means that every property on your type now allow `undefined`:
type localState = {
  settingA?: string | null;
  settingTwo?: string | null;
  otherProperty?: int;
  // etc...
}
```

Which is probably incompatible with *your* version of `localstate`. So, there's two fixes you can choose:

1. Change every property on `localstate` to optional - probably not what you want to do!
2. Use `Pick` and just list the keys you want to change, eg:

```
const newState: Pick<localState, 'settingA' | 'settingTwo'> = {
  settingA: localState.settingA,
  settingTwo: localState.settingTwo,
};

if (newValue !== 2) {
    newState.settingA = null;
    newState.settingTwo = null;
}
newState.multiCurrencyDynamicMode = newValue;
this.setState(newState);
```